# How can I avoid an indirect reference caused by a Friend property?

Tags: .net, vb.net, access-modifiers

Take three VB.net assemblies: A, B, and C.  A references B, and B references C, but A does NOT reference C.  Given the following three classes (one in each assembly):

Assembly A

```
Public Class View()

    Public Property ViewModel as SomeViewModel

End Class
```

Assembly B

```
Public Class SomeViewModel()

    'Compiler is ok with private variable _Model, doesn't complain.
    Private _Model as SomeModel
    Friend Sub New(Model as SomeModel)
        Me._Model = Model
    End Sub

    'Compiler complains when Friend property is added, requiring A to directly
    'reference C.
    Friend ReadOnly Property UnderlyingModel as SomeModel        

End Class
```

Assembly C

```
Public Class SomeModel()

    Public Property ModelID as Integer

End Class
```

In essence, Assembly C contains a model (SomeModel) which is wrapped by SomeViewModel in Assembly B.  SomeViewModel exposes the model to other classes in AssemblyB via a "Friend" property.  The View in Assembly A contains a SomeViewModel, but the SomeViewModel.UnderlyingModel property is inaccessible to the View due to the Friend modifier.

Given this configuration, VS 2010 gives the following compile error when compiling Assembly A:

```
Error   3   Construct makes an indirect reference to project 'AssemblyC',
which contains 'AssemblyC.SomeModel'. Add a project reference to 'AssemblyC' to your
project.
```

Is there a way to expose the UnderlyingModel property via a Friend modifier without having Assembly A reference Assembly C?  I would have thought that the Friend modifier would have made this possible since the View in Assembly A can't access the property that exposes the model in Assembly C?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if you define your property as `Friend` or not.

When the compiler builds your assembly A, it finds a type that is defined in assembly B. I guess you created a project reference so it builds an assembly B too. Now, assembly B needs assembly C to work, you cannot use your solution without it. So this assembly must be available too for the compiler. I guess it could be available as a file reference but if it's your own code, it's more convenient at the end of the day to use project references consistently.

Comment: C is referenced (project reference) by B, so when the compiler builds B it should build C.  Visual Studio is requiring that C be directly referenced by A.  Before adding the Friend property, I had plenty of Private variables in the ViewModel (B) that reference Assembly C, but the compiler doesn't complain about them, only the Friend property.  I'll update my code to show this.

Comment: I can't really reproduce your scenario. It all works for me without compilation errors...

Comment: The real application is, of course, more complicated than the example here.  In the real application the View uses a Binding Source (Windows Forms) to bind to the View Model.  There may be something funny going on with the Binding Source or the Windows Forms designer itself.  I'll see if I can reproduce the problem with just my sample code and report back.